# Receiving Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT error in App Delegate.swift, I am a brand new developer

Tags: swift, xcode, runtime-error

I have looked everywhere and was not able to get an Answer that worked out. I am doing the Apple Tutorial [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1). After I reached a checkpoint where it said run the App to make sure everything works I ran into this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am new developer so every advise I get from you guys will help me out in the future. If more information is necessary let me know and I will gladly provide it!

Comment: Re-check every step carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add view controller class to your view controller on storyboard

[image]

Next drag button and text field

[image]

Then, connect to your code. Text field is connected as IBOutLet and button is connected as action

[image]

Then, add your code like this

```
@IBOutlet weak var text: UITextField!

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
    text.text = "show up"
}
```

Finally, test your result

[image]